# IE: Clicking same button continuously sends same AJAX request multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I've encountered a weird problem. I've bind click method to div using jquery `one()` method.

However, if I click on this div continuously then in IE its executes `AJAX` method 3-4 times. If I disable `AJAX` call and write some other DOM manipulation function, it executes only onces as expected.

I don't why but when I includes `AJAX` call something goes wrong.

I've created sample code at ['http://jsfiddle.net/MCY4A/'](http://jsfiddle.net/MCY4A/) But not sure how to make AJAX call working here in jsfiddle

Somebody please help.

Comment: you might earn another upvote :) if you post some code sample with the issue

Comment: what version of jQuery? http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=one

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand your requirement properly but i assume you want to call ajax request only once on some div click , you can use following code :

```
//declare global var countReq

var reqSend=false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hitme').click(function(){
    if(!reqSend)    {
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/',
                }).success(function(res) {
                    $("#a").insert("<p>success</p>");
                }).error(function(res) {
                    $("#a").insert("<p>error</p>");
                });
reqSend=true;
}
    });
});
```